# Android Manifest Permissions External Storage

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have the below permissions defined in the Manifest but I still see Android asking the app needs permission to write to External storage even though I don't want to access External Storage

Could it be because of Google Play services

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pls try This for google play service error:

```
  <uses-permission
         android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
         android:maxSdkVersion="Version code" />
```

Metadata used end of application.

Comment: I dont want to access external storage but I see Android asking for it.

Comment: You have not paid enough attention to the question, he insist that I am not accessing external storage

Answer (score 2):

It's almost a year since post publication but maybe this'll help someone.
If you are using play-services version < 8.3 then play-services-maps uses this permission.

If you are not using play-services-maps then probably you are using play-services-fitness which takes maps as transitive dependency.

If you are not using nor of them, then probably you have other transitive dependency which needs this permission.

[TIP to check transitive dependencies](https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2014/11/19/gradle-tricks-tracking-down-not-expected-transitive-dependencies/)

Answer (score 1):

Add these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: You have not paid enough attention to the question, he insist that I am not accessing external storage

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of below two reason.

> 1. If you're targeting **version 8.3 or later** of the `Google Play services SDK`, you **no longer need** the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`
>      permission to use the Google Maps Android API.
> 2. If you're targeting **earlier versions** of the Google Play services
>      SDK, **you must request the
>      android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission**.

Check [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/config#specify_android_permissions).

> 2. There was a bug in Google play services that causes unintended `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and
>      `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions to be merged into app manifests. That
>      is solved in *Google Play services 10.0 release*. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases).

To avoid this I recommend to include necessary individual Play service APIs and corresponding build.gradle descriptions. Check [this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project).

Hope this will help you and future user also.

Answer (score 0):

This is missing :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I dont want to access external storage but I see Android asking for it.

Comment: You have not paid enough attention to the question, he insist that I am not accessing external storage